# How to override console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am using the following code to override the `console.log` function, because I want to print `console.log` only if `showConsole` returns `true`.

```
var proxyConsolelog = window.console.log;


console.log=function(msg){
    try{
        if(Boolean(showConsole))
        {
            proxyConsolelog(msg);
        }
    }catch(e){
        alert(JSON.stringify(e.message));
        proxyConsolelog('ERROR-->>'+e.message);
    }
}
```

The `proxyConsolelog` line creates a problem, and `alert(JSON.stringify(e.message));` is giving me a "Type error".

And I get this:

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate
>   (webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:)  failed
>   to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: 
>   kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

in the log.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `proxyConsolelog.apply(console, arguments);`?

Comment: I don't know what's `showConsole` but I doubt it's useful to do `Boolean(showConsole)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you have is that the receiver (`this`) when you call your function, isn't the console.

You can do this :

```
var proxyConsolelog = window.console.log.bind(window.console);
```

If you need to be compatible with IE8 (which doesn't have `bind`), you may do this :

```
var logFun = window.console.log;
var proxyConsolelog = function(){
     logFun.apply(window.console, arguments)
};
```

As you tagged the question [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), then you may also use [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) :

```
var proxyConsolelog = $.proxy(window.console.log, window.console);
```

Once you have your new function, you can call it just like `console.log` :

```
proxyConsolelog('some', {arg:'uments'});
```

Comment: thanks buddy working great!Can u tell me what it 'some' over here

Comment: Your IE8-compatible way won’t work if the point is to override `console.log`, though. :) (Given that this is Cordova, it’s probably safe to not mention it, too.)

Comment: @minitech oh yes, I had overseen the final goal, you're right, thanks. I've edited.

Comment: @dystroy Maybe a dumb question, but what did your last edit actually do? I'm wondering if because I have no experience with Cordova that I'm missing something obvious. But it seems that your last edit just stored a reference to `console.log` (and calling that) instead of directly calling `console.log.apply` (and of course, adding `window.`). Honestly just wondering

Comment: The problem with the previous version is that the `proxyConsolelog` was refering dynamically to `window.console.log`. So it would change as soon as you change `window.console.log` (which happens just after).

Comment: @dystroy Ahh I see, I didn't realize you were only changing the `var proxyConsolelog = window.console.log;` line. I don't know why I didn't think that the rest of the OP's code would still be included. That was silly of me :)

Comment: @lan I put it because I rare knows about js.I am ios developer